# Python obtain the index number of a list after checking with another list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have two list:

```
L1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
L2 = ['h','a','j','b','k','c']
```

I would like to obtain the index number of elements in L2 which are also in L1, ---> [1,3,5].

something like

```
[i for i in L1 if i in L2]
```

would return the element itself rather than element number. Is there an easy way like above?

Comment: `s = set(L1); print( [i for i, v in enumerate(L2) if v in s] )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do :

```
[i for i in range(len(L2)) if L2[i] in L1]
```